# Is there a method that seeks synergies among sports players?

Tags: self-study, correlation, games

I am going to gather data on the performance of individual lineups in NBA matches. I wanted the data to include the average statistics of the players depending on who was with him on the pitch and the statistics of a given lineup. I am looking for a method that allowed me to find synergy effects between players. You can take for example the average of points for DeAndre Jordan when Chris Paul was on the pitch and when he was not there and probably DeAndre threw more on average with Chris Paul on the pitch. But it only takes one variable into account, and it may come out that someone actually threw more points but the other stats dropped a lot. You can calculate the PER factor that takes into account most of the statistics and again count the two ratios with and without a given player on the field and compare but this is just some basic methods. I'm looking for some more complex method. Maybe some kind of correaltion? Can anyone help?

Comment: Of course, the point is that, for example, when two players play together, they have better stats than when they play without each other . But example i describe in question is interesting too for me too, so I would be grateful for any help in any of the cases.

Comment: I am writing my master's thesis and I have to apply the research method. I thought about the cluster analysis, but it doesn't make sense because if we take the lineup and change one player in it, they will most likely be next to each other in the cluster analysis. So I figured out what I described in the question and started browsing the internet but so far I haven't found anything. I need the name of a research method that can give results, which I presented in the question with which I can get acquainted and introduce to my supervisor. As i said I don't even known if method like that exist.

Comment: I will only add that English is not my native language, if something needs clarification, please ask

Comment: essentially the standard approach would be to create a regression model with some interactions between players, and the interactions would be the added value of both players.  However, I feel there must be already some prior modelling/"science" that has been done specifically on basketball. ie what you are describing sounds like "curve fitting" - blindly joining up dots, rather than having a theory of how players teamwork actually increases success.

Comment: on a separate note, there is a whole area of "causal inference" identifying when statistical correlations can identify causal effects: in this case there is no scientist randomly adding or subtracting players in a systematic way - a controlled experiment - absence of players could be down to ? injury etc eg if the player is a substitute and only appears when the better player is injured then it may appear to the model that the substitute model "causes" team performance to drop, whereas it is rather the other way round

Comment: I understand what it is about, but in the case of the question, it does not necessarily depend on whether it affects the team's success. I am interested in basketball and I know that there is a belief that some players received a large contract (they had good statistics) thanks to the fact that they played next to someone who made them 'play better than they could'.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but referring to the second commentary, I do not want to randomly select lienups and take a player from them, I would have the following data (example for one team): staring lineup (P1 P2 P3 P4 P5) - avg stats for them in this lineup, P4 and P5 sub for P6 and P7 and i have lineup P1 P2 P3 P6 P7 and so on so for one team +15 lineups (depending on how many players were subed and how much the coach rotate them.

Comment: In basketball, it is often the case that if we have two stars and one is injured, the other one should actually have a better average of points because the shots thrown by the injured person go largely to the other star. But I am beginning to understand that what I tried to do will not be entirely meaningful. Thank you for your answer, I will have to think about what I can do with this data.